# NullPointerException while trying to findelements

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have created two classes in one package.In first class, i have added some functions and in second class, i have called those methods and also added some more script.

```
        package vma;

        import org.openqa.selenium.By;
        import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
        import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

        import org.testng.Assert;
        import org.testng.annotations.*;


        public class Vehicles {
        static WebDriver driver2;
        @BeforeTest
        public static void start() throws InterruptedException
        {Login.setup(driver2,"FF","S","FS");
        }
        @Test
        public static void step1() throws InterruptedException
        { 
        Thread.sleep(7000);
        driver2.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='mainContainer']/div/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[7]/h3/a")).click();
        driver2.findElement(By.name("make")).sendKeys("AA");
        driver2.findElement(By.name("model")).sendKeys(Model);
        driver2.findElement(By.id("idNext")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        }
        }
```

Now when i run this script.@BeforeTest script run successfully but @Test script gets failed.Error: java.lang.NullPointerException occured.Please guys help me that where i am wrong or what i missed in script.
Exception:

```
FAILED: step1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at vma.Vehicles.step1(Vehicles.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1203)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1128)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1036)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)



    Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Please paste the whole exception.

Comment: The exception will tell you what line it's occurring on. Look at that line and consider all the object references and the operations being performed on them. One of those accounts for your NPE.

Comment: guess: Make sure that `driver2` is not null

Comment: Suspect your driver2 is not getting initialized anywhere in your call.

Comment: yes you are right, driver2 is null.. but another issue is if we add parameter in my methods of first class,, then first method is run then second method throws same null error.

Comment: For Example:
 Login.Browser(driver2,"FF");
 Login.Environment(driver2,"S"); but when i run this script second call throws null error

Comment: Hi, I have made some changes in my code.. but still same null exception for @test is throw.. please check

Comment: How are you invoking your tests?

Comment: See,what i am trying.. i made two classes,,in 1 class i have created one method and in second class,i have called first class methods in under "BeforeTest"annotation and write some more script under @test ..but when i execute the second class.. methods called successfully but after that error thrown for second class script(which i have written in test annotation) .

Answer (score 3):

Is `driver2` is initialized? I don't think so.

For example if your testing against Safari browser, then you need to do something like this:

`WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver()`

And then use this object for your automation.

Comment: i have made some changes in my code and i used FF for running my script.@Before script is run perfectly..there is some error in my @test script

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize your driver2 object? Doesn't look like you did to me. You tried to access its methods but it's null at that point.

Comment: i have made some changes in my code.. please look this and suggest me where i am wrong

Comment: somewhere in your code, you need to initialize your driver2 object something like WebDriver driver2 = new WebDriver();

Comment: No,Webdriver can not be initiated

Comment: Why can it not be initalized? if you *can't* initlialize, you won't be able to call it without running into exceptions...

Answer (score 0):

This is occurs due to the initializing the driver variable and using it. (100% sure)

Try to use it (if you using firefox as a driver)

```
driver2 = new FirefoxDriver();
```